# SunFounder Raspberry Pi CPU/RAM Display Mini LCD 84*48 PCD8544 Shield For Model B+/B

Tags: raspbian, gpio, display, c, c++

this display is driving me nuts!
i almost tried all available samples/libraries.

the only one i got working was this one

https://github.com/ronanguilloux/Raspberry-Pi-Utils

all the other ones either in C or in python - do not work.
i would love to get this one https://github.com/Wicker25/Rpi-hw working (seems to have pretty nice api and nice font support).

is anyone arround helping me to get the rpi-hw working  - seems to be i am to dumb to use the working sample to patch the non-working.

regards

Comment: Assuming you are not tied to C/C++ https://learn.adafruit.com/nokia-5110-3310-lcd-python-library/overview. If you are using a Pi 2 have you enabled the device tree https://blog.adafruit.com/2015/02/27/i2c-spi-i2s-lirc-pps-stopped-working-read-this-piday-raspberrypi-raspberry_pi/

Comment: What kind of Pi are you using?

Comment: dont get me wrong i want (require) to have a C/C++ binding.
i am having a pi2 - will try the device-tree setting when i am at home

Comment: I assume you have to do that in Raspberry Pi 3 also, even with new install from NOOBS? I turned on SPI and I2C with raspi-config and still see nothing on a Sainsmart 5110 plug-in-display.